# Allow website access from specific subnet, otherwise ask for credentials

Tags: iis, iis-6, authentication, ip-address, http-basic-authentication

How can I configure IIS 6 to allow access to a sub folder

1. from our intranet without any authentication (well, the IP address needs to be checked but that's already working)
2. from the internet only after authentication via Basic Auth?

Basically I'm looking for something like the [Satisfy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#satisfy) directive in Apache httpd.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe IIS 6 allows such level of control without a custom ISAPI filter of some sort.  Like [AuthentiX](http://www.flicks.com/flicks/authx.htm) for example.